# Make a div able to run onclick function when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am creating an options menu for a notes-app.  I want to make the menu show when you click the three-dots(these are stored in a div).  When I put an onclick with a function on the element, it does not run the function.  I want to know how to make this div clickable, if this is the problem.  Adding the click event listener from javascript works only for the existing note I have, but I add new notes from javascript later, and this does not work with the javascript notes.  This is the code:

```js
function showOptions() {
  alert('hi');
  $('#delete').closest('.options-menu').fadeToggle(200);
}
```

```html
<div class="option-holder">
  <input type="text" name="note-title" id="note-title" placeholder="Your note title">
  <div class="note-options">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="options-menu" onclick="showOptions()">
      <h3 id="delete">Delete</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please tell me how to get the click function working.  Thank you!

Comment: The example you posted works perfectly fine, although you didn't import jquery in the snippet so it's not able to execute the `fadeToggle()` function in the interactive window,

Comment: can you clarify what constitutes the actual `note` itself in the above? Is all of what we see above a single note? And the aim is to click the 3 dots to reveal the hidden menu ( with `delete` ? )

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes.  It did solve my problem.  I realized I was targeting the wrong element(I think), but still, it did not work with the click I was using.  Your code did solve that issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in `jQuery` using the `.on()` method since the items are being added dynamically to the DOM.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'div.options-menu', function() {
    alert('hi');
    $('#delete').closest('.options-menu').fadeToggle(200);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="option-holder">
  <input type="text" name="note-title" id="note-title" placeholder="Your note title">
  <div class="note-options">
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="options-menu">
      <h3 id="delete">Delete</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```